# How can i remove the oldest entries in my SQL result?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to get only the last reports, for all items but only *the most recent* report for each `item_id`.
Here is my current solution:

```
SELECT distinct * FROM t.reports ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 100
```

My table consists of the following columns:

```
id | user | item_id |  created
'2', '1',   '2643',  '2017-06-13 16:28:34'
'3', '1',   '19333', '2017-06-13 19:26:56'
'4', '1',   '19333', '2017-06-13 19:29:24'
'5', '1',   '1319',  '2017-06-13 19:29:56'
'6', '1',   '1319',  '2017-06-13 19:30:16'
'7', '1',   '1319',  '2017-06-13 19:30:17'
'8', '1',   '1319',  '2017-06-13 19:30:18'
'9', '1',   '1319',  '2017-06-13 19:30:25'
'10','1',   '1319',  '2017-06-13 19:31:51'
```

I want no duplicate item_ids AND only the most recent entry for that item.
BUT i also want ALL reports, but no duplicate item reports!

EXAMPLE:
i expect that when i execute my query, i only get row 2,4 and 10 returned.

Comment: `DISTINCT *` is oxymoronic

Comment: I think you need to give us a more specific explanation of what you want. Maybe with some examples

Comment: Check my updated q.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm mostly curious as to the commas in there.

Comment: I would guess a copy/paste from something, but who knows @Fred-ii-

Comment: Only [*"Heaven Knows..."*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IvyG7E-qf0o) @RiggsFolly

Comment: Or "_[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4h-TmhXavdw)_" @Fred-ii-

Comment: Funny that; which is what I also thought of earlier as a "tacked on" after the other fact; yep... you nailed it buddy @RiggsFolly it's a good one ♫

Comment: @Fred-ii- it's copy/paste from MySQL Workbench results... I KNOW, but if you have a better solution i'll be happy to apply it on my next questions.

Comment: See, I didn't know that ;-) This could have swung another way, where you could very well have been storing comma-separated values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select a.id,a.user,a.item_id,a.created
from reports as a
where a.created=(select max(created) 
                from reports as b
                where a.item_id=b.item_id)
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining the SQL so that i understand it better ?

Comment: @Oliver Hoff, You need the latest report so the first thing you do is looking for the highest date (created) for each item_id, that´s what you do in the subquery. Once you you know the max date you just select the report that corresponds to that date

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by :

```
SELECT * FROM t.reports WHERE created IN (SELECT max(created) FROM t.reports) 
GROUP BY item_id
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: this is not working as well, it will return first date from database with same `item_id` it will not find latest date

Answer (score 0):

Try with this I have tested it on my test database:

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_id, MAX(created), id, user
FROM `t.reports`
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY MAX(created) DESC
```

Comment: invalid GROUP BY https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Answer (score 0):

Try This let me know if this works.

```
SELECT * 
FROM t.reports 
where item_id in (
                    select distinct item_id 
                    from t.reports
                ) 
ORDER BY updated DESC 
LIMIT 100
```