# Can someone explain this SQL for me?

Tags: mysql, sql

I got this SQL as an answer in a previous question, but i did not get any response in explaining the query. So i am asking here.
My previous question: [How can i remove the oldest entries in my SQL result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44543764/how-can-i-remove-the-oldest-entries-in-my-sql-result)

```
select a.id,
       a.user,
       a.item_id,
       a.created
  from reports as a
 where a.created = (select max(created) 
                      from reports as b
                     where a.item_id = b.item_id)
```

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: Please link at least to the other question so we have some context!

Comment: I want it explained - part by part, to understand the full query

Comment: @JohannesStadler i edited my question and added a link to my other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a table called `reports` and you are extracting a table that consists of the `id`, `user`, `item_id`, and `created` fields. This new table will only have rows that contain the max value of `created` for each distinct `item_id`.

This part extracts the fields you want:

```
select a.id,
       a.user,
       a.item_id,
       a.created
```

From a table called reports (a):

```
  from reports as a
```

Only extract the rows that satisfy the condition:

```
 where a.created = (select max(created) 
                      from reports as b
                     where a.item_id = b.item_id)
```

Comment: Could you explain the condition as well ?

Comment: '3', '1',   '19333', '2017-06-13 19:26:56'
'4', '1',   '19333', '2017-06-13 19:29:24' you have same item_id, right? but two different timestamp, so you pick the most recent one, max(created)

Comment: In @MiloBellano's example above, you would have two rows with the same item_id, so your query would select the row that has the max value for the created field (most recent date)

Answer (score 1):

The following sub query is return max created result (i think it's date column so last created date will be return)

```
 select max(created) 
                  from reports as b
                 where a.item_id = b.item_id
```

Based on that result  in report table create column is match that value and return the result .
The following line is match the both table item_id column.

```
where a.item_id = b.item_id
```

Comment: The sub query returns max created result for each distinct item_id, as opposed to the global max.